# Modifying the variable's value during debugging perl code

Tags: linux, perl, debugging

I was debugging a perl program on SuSe Linux using "perl -d" switch.

While debugging, the program was reporting `XYZ variable is not set`

How can I set the value of XYZ inside the debugger?

I tried following inside the debugger but not working.

```
set XYZ=ABC
my $XYZ=ABC
setenv XYZ ABC
```

I did a bit of google on this. But couldn't find what I wanted.

Comment: Can you show the part of the program that reported it?

Comment: Perl does not emit that message. What is the actual message you got?

Comment: @ikegami: Perl didn't report it. My program reported. ;-)

Comment: You're saying it does `print "XYX variable is not set";`? How are we suppose to know the reason it does, then?

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned the code. But I thought its irrelevant to mention the code. But anyways I will keep in mind next time.

Comment: @SSHegde have a look at http://sscce.org/ and http://whathaveyoutried.com, they are both helpful resources on how to ask good questions in the programming world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debug console takes Perl expressions, so you need to quote the value if it is a string.

You will have to move the program to before the line that throws the error (look at breakpoints, it's `b <line>` in the debugger) and then set the value.

```
> $XYZ='ABC'
```

Here's a good resource: http://obsidianrook.com/devnotes/talks/perl_debugger/

Comment: @simbabque: can you do this when using the "Eclipse" debugger? (With the Perl plugin "EPIC")?

Comment: @HelenCraigman probably. I have never used the Eclipse debugger, but it would certainly suck if it couldn't do that. The Komodo debugger can do it, so I'm fairly certain Eclipse can. You can most likely set breakpoints by clicking on line numbers (or near them). You can also step through the code with the button that has a down-pointing arrow. This is like any graphical debugger, e.g. the JS debugger in Firebug. Check this out: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-epic/

Comment: @simbabque: I meant changing variable values during program run. I have been using the Eclipse/EPIC debugger extensively, I find it very powerful and feature-rich, (including, of course, setting breakpoints,  code-stepping, and inspecting vaiables). The only thing I couldn't find how to do is modify variable values at breakpoints.

Comment: @HelenCraigman: Oh. Well, I don't know how to do that in Eclipse. Maybe you can just double-click values where you inspect them? I'd just ask that as a question in the `java` and `eclipse` tags if I were you. They'll know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are trying to set $XYZ to the string ABC try:

```
$XYZ = 'ABC'
```

If you use

```
my $XYZ='ABC'
```

it will define the variable $XYZ in the current scope only. From testing in the debugger it looks like that scope does not extend outside the debug console (i.e it is only accessible on that line of the console). E.G.

```
  DB<2> my $x = "hello"; print "$x"
hello
  DB<3> print $x
Use of uninitialized value $x in print at (eval 8)[/usr/share/perl/5.12/perl5db.pl:638] line 2.
```